# Facebook iOS SDK DemoApp shows "Sorry, an error has occurred" even after App ID configuration

Tags: ios, facebook

I downloaded the Facebook iOS SDK from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/.
I opened the DemoApp, and I've set my app id in the code and in the application's plist for the url callback.
When I run it on both simulator and device, as soon I hit the Login button, it opens up a Safari window displaying "Sorry, an error has occurred." on the Facebook page. My system clock is accurate (this was someone else's issue).

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it. I was passing in my app's API Key, not the App ID!

Comment: Thank you! I've spent an hour now trying to find what was wrong. Did the exact same thing...